# Update the disk storage type in azure windows vm using ansible playbook

Tags: azure, jenkins, ansible, virtual-machine

I have written 4 tasks for it first for power off the vm, second to verify if it is stopped, 3rd to update and then power on the vm. But the problem is even when the machine is stopped ansible is giving error "Operation not allowed". You can see the error below. Please suggest me the correct way of doing it as I am new to ansible. Please also clarify which task to run on localhost and which on windows.

fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Error creating the managed disk: Azure Error: OperationNotAllowed\nMessage: Cannot change account type, fault domain or network spine of disk <<disk_name>> while it is attached to running VM <<vm_name>>."}

```
- name: Update Disk type
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
  - name: Power off the VM
    azure_rm_virtualmachine:
      resource_group: "{{resource_group}}"
      name: "{{vm_name}}"
      started: no

  - name: Verify that the machine is stopped
    win_ping:
    #delegate_to: localhost
    failed_when: false
    ignore_unreachable: true
    register: ping_result

  - debug: var=ping_result

  - name: Update the disk type
    azure_rm_manageddisk:
      name: "{{disk_name}}"
      resource_group: "{{resource_group}}"
      storage_account_type: "{{type}}"
      disk_size_gb: "{{size}}"
 
  - name: Power on the VM
    azure_rm_virtualmachine:
      resource_group: "{{resource_group}}"
      name: "{{vm_name}}"
```

Comment: Hello @Richa Tiwari, the code seems to be correct but as per the error the update of a disk is not allowed a disk is attached to the VM.. So I would suggest you to try using "allocated: no" instead of "started: no" and then check if the operation succeeds

Comment: Thanks for your answer. And yes you are right I have tried the same and it worked. VM completely stopped only when I used allcated: no instead of started. Now its working fine. 
And one more point I like to add is that for disk updation one need to use the azure cli command instead of ansible module. Because it is mentioned in the Github repo for ansible that disk updation is not possible through ansible module due to some server constraints.

Comment: Good to hear that .. thanks for your update as well .. Let me post it as an answer

Answer (score 0):

The issue was resolved by changing

```
name: Power off the VM
    azure_rm_virtualmachine:
      resource_group: "{{resource_group}}"
      name: "{{vm_name}}"
      started: no
```

to

```
name: Power off the VM
    azure_rm_virtualmachine:
      resource_group: "{{resource_group}}"
      name: "{{vm_name}}"
      allocated: no
```

Also as per **Richa's Update** we need to use az CLI to update the disk as it is mentioned in Github repo for ansible that disk updation is not possible through ansible module due to some server constraints.

**Reference**: [az disk | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/disk?view=azure-cli-latest#az_disk_update)